# How do I check if a folder contains a certain type of file with AppleScript?

Tags: file, applescript

First time applescripting and I have put together a script that creates a .nfo file containing the [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/) link to a movie based on the folder name.

Currently the script is setup to ask user for a folder which contains all their movies and it loops though that folder until all the subfolders have been processed.

The structure is:

- Movies

  - movie 1

    - video file
    - movie 1.nfo
  - movie 2

    - video file
    - movie 2.nfo
  - movie 3

    - video file
    - movie 3.nfo

and so on...

I need help adding an if-then-else statement that first checks to see if a nfo file is already present and in case it is, just increase the counter to move on to the next folder or else run my current script code.

I have tried stuff like

```
if (theFiles contains files whose name extension is nfo) then
    i = i + 1
else
    -- My Code
end if
```

It doesn't seem to care and just processes all folders again replacing the current nfo with a new one.

Current AppleScript:

```
property imdburl : ""
property newurl : ""
property FolderPath1 : ""
property FolderPath : ""
property Foldername : ""

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set theFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select the Movie Folder."
    set theList to every folder of theFolder
    repeat with i from 1 to count the theList
        set thisItem to item i of theList as alias
        set currentName to name of thisItem
        --set currentfolder to get the POSIX path of thisItem
        set theFiles to every file of folder thisItem as alias list

        if (theFiles contains files whose name extension is nfo) then
            i = i + 1
        else
            tell application "Finder"
                set FolderPath1 to thisItem -- sets file path to folder you select
                set ParentFolder to container of FolderPath1 -- sets the parent folder of the folder you select
                set Foldername to name of folder FolderPath1 -- sets the folder name as text
                set FolderPath to get the POSIX path of FolderPath1
                set newurl to "http://google.com/search?q=" & Foldername & "+imdb&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky"
                --set the clipboard to newurl -- sets foldername to the clipboard
            end tell

            tell application "Safari"
                open location newurl
                activate
                delay 3
                set imdburl to URL of current tab of window 1
                set the clipboard to FolderPath
                close window 1
            end tell

            tell application "TextEdit"
                activate
                make new document
                set text of document 1 to imdburl
                set Foldername to text 1 thru -(7 + 1) of Foldername
                save document 1 in FolderPath & "/" & Foldername
                close document 1
            end tell

            tell application "Finder" to set name extension of (files of FolderPath1 whose name extension is "rtf") to "nfo"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example shows how to check for an application package in a folder (just to make it easy to test). Replace .app with .ifo and you have what you want.

```
on foo()
    tell application "Finder"
        set someFolder to choose folder
        set aList to name of files of someFolder as list
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
        return ".app" is in (aList & return as text)
    end tell
end foo

on run {}
    foo()
end run
```

Note that contrary to what is often stated, a repeat loop is not necessary to get a list of files of a folder.

Comment: had to use this as a branch off point to get the if statement to work <br> set aList to name of files of thisItem as list
  set currentnfo to text 1 thru -(7 + 1) of currentName
  if (currentnfo & ".nfo" is in (aList)) then
   i = i + 1
  else

Comment: Note that this approach won't work with hidden Finder items such as e.g. `.git` folders unless Finder configuration is explicitly changed to display such items.